# include Gtk in py2exe

Tags: python, gtk, py2exe, importerror

i wrote a little tool and want to compile it with py2exe to a stand-alone-binary file.

I tried it with 'py2exe' to make this happen.

My .py-file works as I want it to do.

But after generating the .exe I get the following error executing it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "league.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "gi\__init__.pyc", line 42, in <module>

  File "gi\_gi.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gi\_gi.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(name="LoL-CLI",
      version="1.0",
      console=['league.py'],
      options={"py2exe": {
            'dll_excludes':['libglib-2.0-0.dll',
                            'libgirepository-1.0-1.dll',
                            'libffi-6.dll',
                            'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                            'libcairo-gobject-2.dll']
                        }
            }
)
```

I think that my python interpreter can find the gi library, but py2exe doesn't.
I exclude all the DLLs because it gives me errors not finding these DLLs and google said I should exclude it.

I also find the solution that I copy the "gi" folder to 'dist' after executing "setup.py py2exe" but it didn't work.

Appreciate any tipps or thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you may need to explicitly define all the modules that your gtk application depends on.

```
options={"py2exe": {
            'dll_excludes':['libglib-2.0-0.dll',
                            'libgirepository-1.0-1.dll',
                            'libffi-6.dll',
                            'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                            'libcairo-gobject-2.dll']
                        },
             'includes': 'gi, cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject, gio, gtk.keysyms',
            }
```